# Unable to provide SagePay Key and Secret with Omnipay, "Attempted to call an undefined method named setKey"

Tags: symfony, opayo, omnipay

I've been integrating the Omnipay library with my Symfony2 project and I'm using the Server method to deal with the transactions. I have a key and secret provided to me by SagePay.

However, in my code I'm providing the details like this:

```
    $gateway = OmniPay::create($gateway_server)
        ->setVendor(getenv('MYVENDOR'))
        ->setTestMode(true)
        ->setKey('MYKEY')
        ->setSecret('MYSECRET');
```

However, I get the following message:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "setKey" of class
>   "Omnipay\SagePay\ServerGateway".

And when I remove the `setKey` method, I get this error:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "setSecret" of class
>   "Omnipay\SagePay\ServerGateway".

Removing both of these results in this error message:

> Server error response [status code] 500 [reason phrase] Internal
>   Server Error [url]
>   https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspserver-register.vsp

I haven't been given access to SagePay to check error logs at the moment, but I am working to the idea that because I'm not providing the data submission with a key and secret it's causing an error.

Any idea why the `setKey` and `setSecret` are undefined, and how I would pass these on to SagePay in the server configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to using the [Dwolla/omnipay-dwolla version](https://github.com/Dwolla/omnipay-dwolla), instead of the thephpleague/omnipay-sagepay version. I see some differences...

Comment: Only problem with Dwolla is that it relies on you to sign up to their API, which going forward could cause issues with the project if they decide to stop maintaining their API.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using the SagePay ServerGateway ($gateway_server == SagePay_Server) you apparently don't need to provide the key and secret.

Your gateway initialisation should look like this:

```
$gateway = Omnipay::create('SagePay_Server')
    ->setVendor($api_vendor)
    ->setTestMode($testMode);
```

Which doesn't answer the question as to why you're seeing this error:

```
Server error response [status code] 500 [reason phrase] Internal Server Error [url]
```

... however I don't believe that it's due to not providing the API key and secret.

There is an unmerged PR (with some issues) here, which contains a sample working implementation using SagePay:

https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-sagepay/pull/45

Answer (score 0):

The key and secret is not needed for either Sage Pay Server or Sage Pay Direct, since both rely (for better or worse) on knowing your IP address when sending messages. The IP address is the authentication.

The newer [Sage Pay Pi](https://test.sagepay.com/documentation/#authentication) uses a key and secret for authentication, and does not look at IP addresses at all. This is not yet supported by OmniPay at all. There are standalone packages for handling that gateway though.

There is mention of the Dwolla package in another answer, which does take a key and secret. In that case, a third party is placing itself between your site and Sage Pay, and it is that third party that requires the key and secret, *not* Sage Pay.